# Is "Extract" a reserved word in Excel or VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is "Extract" a reserved word in Excel-2016 or VBA for Excel?

I was writing a custom function to find and extract a portion from a complex set of tuples. Naturally I named the function Extract and got the  message "This function is invalid" from the spreadsheet (not the VBA development window). I checked the reserved words list for Excel and for VBA and did not see "extract." After wasting an hour or so, I renamed the function (and its return assignments) to simply "Ex" and it was accepted and worked.

So now I can't stop wondering if there's a hidden function in Excel and how it could be used. Any ideas?

Larry

Answer (score 0):

"Extract" does not belong to reserved word.

In my test, it can be used as a function name.

Please check and make sure that no other reserved words are misused in your code.
[image]